# missing 'jump to source button' on TeXtudio?

Tags: texstudio

I use TeXstudio and for some reason the jump to source button disappeared on my newly compiled files when I right click, but it is still there when I compile older files. The packages I used are the same, what is causing the problem?

The use manual says:

> TexMakerX provides an integrated `pdf-viewer` which offers forward- and
>   inverse-search. Make sure that `synctex` is activated in the `pdflatex`
>   command (option `-synctex=1` needs to be added), though TexMakerX will
>   ask you if it can correct the command itself if it is not set
>   correctly.

This option is activated, so why is the button still gone?

Comment: actually I found it under advanced options, it was always there but the button is still missing!?

Comment: What is your OS? Are you using `-synctex=1` with `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Sigur yes, these were default settings I never touched. my OS is windows 7. I have a problem with my OS right now, because the IT services at my university reinstalled it for me after I had a system crash, but they did not activate it. Surely that cannot be the root of the problem though?

Comment: After running `pdflatex` (via editor)  can you find on the same folder some compressed file with `synctex` on its name?

Comment: @Sigur no! but they are there for previously built files

Comment: So, this is the reason. The info about the file to be used on inverse search are stored on that file. If it does not exists... Do you know how to run `pdflatex` using the prompt command (that black window with command line)? You can run `pdflatex -synctex=1 myfile.tex` directly to see if the compressed file is created.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12820/discussion-between-lost1-and-sigur)

Comment: @Sigur i have not done that before and i pull up a latex command window. 'MikTex 2.9\miktex\bin\latex.exe' it asks me for the name of your input file. I think I typed in the right thing, it says nothing found

Comment: @Sigur thank you for your time. I have solved this problem. if you are curious, then read the answer. :) wouldn't have done it if you didn't raise the issue about the missing synctex file which I then googled.

Comment: I don't have this problem using TeXstudio on Linux. I simply use the code `%.tex` to cite my input `tex` file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have solved this. This is the problem which occurs here

http://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/user-reports/1296/

Basically it does not work because there is a space in the file name.

Comment: Just in case someone have the same problem, it does happen if you have special characters like "ç, ã" in your file name as well.

Comment: Spaces and Accented characters MAY cause a problem on SOME (not all) systems. the problems as linked with TeXnicCenter were due to DDE not handling those characters.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is so generally. In my case, I changed from -synctex=0 to -synctex=1 in my default compiler Xelatex. Try to change it at the place of your default compiler instaed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for my `XeLatex`.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same situation. I updated the system and installed texstudio-dbg from synaptic package. Then it's working.

Comment: Spaces and Accented characters MAY cause a problem on SOME (not all) systems. the problems as linked with TeXnicCenter were due to DDE not handling those characters.